# How add EmailComposeTask to RichTextBox in Windows Phone App?

Tags: windows-phone-7, richtextbox

I am want enabled email address in RichTextBox, I search word with @ in text and want to add EmailComposeTask in paragraph. Is this possible??

```
if (word.Contains("@"))
{
    ???
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(????);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
foreach (var word in text)
{
    if (word.Contains("@")
    {
        var link = new Hyperlink
        {
            Command = new EmailComposeCommand(),
            CommandParameter = word
        };

        link.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = word });

        paragraph.Inlines.Add(link
    }
    else
    {
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = word });
    }
}



public class ClickToCallCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.ToString());
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var ect = new EmailComposeTask
            {
                To = parameter.ToString()
            };

        ect.Show();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Add appropriate error handling, etc. as necessary.